# is there any way to reposition a win32 calculator application to a specific coordinate in the desktop?

Tags: java, awtrobot

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class calc_robo_mouse
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
                           AWTException, InterruptedException
    {
        String command = "calc.exe";
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        run.exec(command);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(350,400);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    robot.mouseMove(100, 100);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    }
}
```

this program only moves the mouse pointer but i need to move the application itself to a different position. please do help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the mouse press occur in the title bar of the calculator ?

Comment: Does the solution have to be platform independent?